# Calculating the average vector for each unique element in a list

Tags: python, list, vector, list-comprehension, average

I have a list of the form:

```
mylist =[([256, 408, 147, 628], 'size'), ([628, 526, 236, 676], 'camera'),
 ([526, 876, 676, 541], 'camera'), ([567, 731, 724, 203], 'size'),.....]
```

That has a size of around 8000+.

It contains many duplicate entries, there are actually only 100 unique words in this list and so I would like to reduce this list down to a size of 100 (the number of unique words) by taking the average vector of every occurance of that word.

For example, my new list will have the form:

```
newlist = [([411.5,569.5,435.5,415.5],'size',.....] #I have taken the average values of 'size' 
here and want to repeat this for each unique word
```

and will be of length 100.

How would I do this?

Comment: You might be better off having you final result in a dictionary, if that fits your workflow. Doing that, iterate over the list. When you find a new word, add it to the dictionary along with its "vector", when you find an existing word, just add the vector t the previous dictionary entry. After that, do a pass over the dictionary and average all the saved vectors.

Comment: @Puff I think I get what you mean but I'm not sure I know how to do this

Comment: @martineau I have tried to implement a for loop to iterate over the list but I don't know how to average the vectors for every occurance while doing this

Comment: Give it a try, we can help you as you get stuck. I can also recommend you use `numpy.mean` to calculate the mean once you've grouped your vectors into lists.

Comment: Show as an attempt and I'll gladly help you fix/finish it.

Comment: @Puff someone has answered the question in the way you have explained, good thinking! and thanks for explaining the process to me, I understand it now

Comment: Yes, bu they defeated the purpose of you learning by trying. People tend to rush to make answers sometimes, instead of letting the asker learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by collecting all the data for each 'key' into a dict, then work out the average for each element in each list assigned to that key. Something like:

```
from statistics import mean

data = [([1, 2, 3, 4], 'size'), ([10, 20, 30, 40], 'camera'),
 ([100, 200, 300, 400], 'camera'), ([10, 20, 30, 40], 'size')]

ddata = {}
for entry in data:
    key = entry[-1]
    if not key in ddata:
        ddata[key] = []
    ddata[key].append(entry[0])

#print(ddata)

out = []
for k, v in ddata.items():
    out.append((list(map(mean, zip(*v))), k))

print(out)
# [([5.5, 11, 16.5, 22], 'size'), ([55, 110, 165, 220], 'camera')]
```

Comment: I'd argue `np.mean(v, axis=0)` is cleaner and clearer, but you could also say that a solution with built-in libraries is preferred over one with third-party ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this! Let me know if you like it :)

Note that the final output is my_new_list, soy check it out doing:
`print(my_new_list)` at the end.

```
mylist_names = set([item[1] for item in mylist])


my_new_list = []

for name in mylist_names:
    name_list = [item[0] for item in mylist if item[1] == name]
    name_list = np.mean(name_list, axis=0).tolist()
    my_new_list.append((name_list, name))
```

Comment: With this solution you are iterating 100 times over the 8000 long list (the solution is O(n*m) instad of the proposed O(n), with n being the size of the list and m the amount of distinct names).

Comment: This is a really useful observation. Thank you!  I'll keep it in mind.